# how to create time for note app

Tags: android, time, textview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `TextView` to show style time follow: `"HH:mm"`, but how to know the current time has passed 23:59? I want to set style time follow: `"dd/MM"` if next day.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first you must save time data with format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ". After check if data date equals date now and format data dat "HH:mm". If data date - Date now > 0 and < 7, format date "dd, E".

Comment: I mean hours of day, not day of week. thanks for your answer :)